# CSS - 100%px fixes my issue?

Tags: css

I have a question on something weird that is rendering on the latest IE and Chrome browsers.  I have a div that is supposed to span 100% of a parent.  So clumsily, I gave it - width: 100%px; as a CSS property. Here is my entire item:

```
.loc_vendiv{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

The weird thing - that worked perfectly.  So much so, that I just noticed today that this was wrong.  Not wanting an ugly style sheet, I removed the px from the end.  And... the div was two pixels too wide. Any explanation as to why this is happening?  Here is the parent div:

```
#loc_catlist{
    position: absolute;
    width: 612px;
    height: 720px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I'm mildly annoyed, as the bad code works, yet the correct code doesn't do what I want.  I don't think I can leave it, though.  I don't like little hiccups like this...

Comment: Browsers usually ignore invalid css rules. Try to remove the `width` rule completly

Comment: you can't set `width: 100%px`, choose `px` or `%`

Comment: @AleshaOleg has said in the question. he already know that.

Comment: @litelite - Yes.  I was able to remove the width entirely, but from my experience, divs don't usually stretch to 100% width without content to push them.  How in the heck did this div decide to simply widen out?

Comment: divs are blocks they take all the width. you are probably thinking about span

Comment: You can also take a look at [`calc`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) which accepts an expression that can include percentage, ems or pxs. This, along with `box-sizing`, makes it easy to manipulate elements' dimensions.

Comment: @litelite Haha.  Nope, I was thinking about divs.  Problem is, I'm one of those self-taught guys, so sometimes I just don't know/play by the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of your border.
Try adding :

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your `.loc_vendiv` class, it will take the border in account.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers usually ignore invalid css rules like `width: 100%px;` which means that to get the style you had with the mistake. you only have to remove the width rule.

Answer (score 1):

2px too wide is likely caused because you have a width of 100% in addition to a border of 1px (all around adds up to 2px width).

A fix can be found here from "Paul Irish" about
[box-sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: Thank you.  That page has some good information that I was completely unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

what happens is that when the width value is wrong (100%px;) this part of the CSS is simply ignored by the browser. If this part of the css was deleted, the result would be the same.

About the 2 extra pixels, this happens because of the border set to the div.loc_vendiv.

The width of div.loc_vendiv is equal to the width of div#loc_catlist and to this is added the border value (1px for the left border and 1px for the right border = 2px).

Remember that the border width is added to the size of the object while the padding creates an internal space.